# Combine RedirectMatch and RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to combine a redirect with a rewrite.
The rewrite should match for a complete path but the redirect should only match for a subpath.

Url: http://localhost/mypath/google

Expected: Redirect to http://www.google.com/

Actual: Rewrite to  http://stackoverflow.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch ^/mypath/google/(.*) http://www.google.com/
RewriteRule   ^/mypath/(.*)$  http://stackoverflow.com [L,P]
```

Obviously the RewriteRule always matches. Is it possible to change the rules, so that the RedirectMatch rules are checked in the first place?

Comment: What’s with the quotes around the regular expression and the target URL …?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But the quotes dont't make any difference. Nevertheless I just edited the question for simplicity.

Comment: Not sure if those two directives are actually evaluated in the order the are written in (they are part of different modules after all) – I’d suggest you simply do both things using RewriteRules instead.

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution: RewriteRule .... [R]

Comment: OK, let me add that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the processing of a request, Apache invokes its different modules in a certain order – so you can not assume that all directives you write in a configuration file in a specific order will also be “executed” in that order.

Since `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule` are from different modules, I suppose that’s the case here – your `RewriteRule` gets processed first, and rewrites everything starting with `/mypath/`, and so your `RedirectMatch` doesn’t have a chance to jump on that train any more …

So the easiest solution would be to handle *both* redirects using RewriteRules, dealing with the more specific path first, and then catch the rest using the second rule you already have in place.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/mypath/google/(.*) http://www.google.com/ [R]
RewriteRule ^/mypath/(.*)$  http://stackoverflow.com [L,P]
```